# How can I configure Mako to automatically re-compile after each editing of the template?

Tags: mako

I'm using Mako for my static files templating. After each editing and saving, I have to re-start my web application in order to see the effects. Can I configure Mako to automatically re-compile on each save?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for caching and filesystem-based templates:

- https://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/usage.html
- https://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/caching.html

Do you have page caching enabled?

```
<%page cached="True"/>
```

> ## Cache Arguments
>
> On a Template or TemplateLookup, the caching can be configured using these arguments:
>
> cache_enabled - Setting this to False will disable all caching functionality when the template renders. Defaults to True. e.g.:

```
lookup = TemplateLookup(
                directories='/path/to/templates',
                cache_enabled = False
                )
```

> ## Using File-Based Templates
>
> A Template can also load its template source code from a file, using the filename keyword argument:

```
from mako.template import Template

mytemplate = Template(filename='/docs/mytmpl.txt')
print(mytemplate.render())
```

> For improved performance, a Template which is loaded from a file can also cache the source code to its generated module on the filesystem as a regular Python module file (i.e. a .py file). To do this, just add the module_directory argument to the template:

```
from mako.template import Template

mytemplate = Template(filename='/docs/mytmpl.txt', module_directory='/tmp/mako_modules')
print(mytemplate.render())
```

> When the above code is rendered, a file /tmp/mako_modules/docs/mytmpl.txt.py is created containing the source code for the module. The next time a Template with the same arguments is created, this module file will be automatically re-used.

Comment: This answer is completely missing my question.